# Creating output file according to date in oozie

Tags: date, hadoop, file-io, oozie

I am using oozie to run my map-reduce job. I want to create the output file according to the date. But it takes date as a string and ends up printing instead of taking date as the value :

```
   /user/skataria/geooutput/$(date +"%m%d%Y%H%M%S")
```

Here is the oozie properties file:

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8021
date=(date +"%m%d%Y%H%M%S")
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/services/advert/sid
inputDir=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/geoinput/testgeo
outputDir=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/geooutput/${date}
```

**Somehow i cant have oozie as tag because my reputation is under 1500**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use a linux shell command (`date +"%m%d%Y%H%M%S"`) in a java properties file - this isn't going to resolve.

One work around, assuming this is part of a manually submitted Workflow job (as opposed to a Coordinator job) is to provide the date property from the command line using the -D key=value option, and linux shell back quotes to resolve the output of a command inline

```
oozie job -run -config job.properties -D date=`date +"%m%d%Y%H%M%S"`
```

You'll need to make sure your version of Oozie support the -D key=value option

Comment: Will certainly give this a try.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree the shell option works. But that does not solve my usecase. I want to run my map-reduce job daily and schedule this thru Hue. The output directory needs to be parameterized as an job property to Oozie.

By the way I find that [Oozie has Expression language Functions](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2_Expression_Language_Functions),

Unfortunately the function `timestamp()` returns the UTC current date and time in W3C format down to the second `(YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ)`. i.e.: `1997-07-16T19:20:30.45Z` and completely unusable for creating a sub-directory name in HDFS

So for now,

I have a workaround. I am using the Workflow EL Function `wf:id()`
In `workflow.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir</name>
  <value>/user/sasubramanian/impressions/output/outpdir/${yyyy_mm_dd}/${wf:id()}</value>
</property>
```

This creates a output directory with subdirectory as,

```
/user/foouser/subdir1/output/outpdir/0000006-130321100837625-oozie-oozi-W
```

NOTE: You must specify this in the workflow.xml. This will not work if you specified it in the job.properties